# Regex to extract RGB(r,g,b) from RGBA(r,g,b,a)

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I am running the following regex in JS to extract 3 R/G/B items from the string below which is `rgba(r,g,b,a)`, but it's not working. I am getting the original string back.

```js
var str = 'rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3)';
/* Goal: rgb(14,48,71) */

console.log (str.replace(/^rgba\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),(\d+.\d+)\)$/, 'rgb($1,$2,$3)'));
```

Comment: You're missing the `\s*` in front of your last capture group.

Comment: [Visualize It](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ergba%5C%28%28%5Cd%2B%29%2C%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%2C%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%2C%28%5Cd%2B.%5Cd%2B%29%5C%29%24%2F) and it will stand out why

Comment: Is your intent to make this work with any CSS `rgba()` expression? If so, you're going to have to consider [valid expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) like `rgba(1e2, .5e1, .5e0, +.25e2%)`.

Comment: Your regex should be 

`rgba?\((\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*)(((?:,\s*[0-9.]*\s*)?))\)`

Was missing the third group

Comment: That may be valid @JordanRunning, but do you actually have a use case in mind for CSS being written that way? I totally endorse supporting edge cases, but that seems like a case in which you'd want it to fail and pose some questions to whoever's writing color values with that syntax

Comment: @jmcgriz My point was that there are a lot of edge cases that OP at least needs to _consider_. Percent values for the alpha component are common. It's also common for people to leave off `0` in the ones place (i.e. `.3` for `0.3`), or to see just `0` or `1`. None of those cases are covered by OP's original regexp. Finally, CSS isn't just written by people. There are lots of tools that generate CSS code, and CSS color values in particular, and we can't make assumptions about what number format(s) they'll use.

Comment: @JordanRunning Fair enough, the machine-generated CSS is a good point. In my answer below it uses `.+` to match the opacity section anyway to avoid worrying about the format, since OP doesn't care about capturing the alpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also write a more consolidated version of the regex like this:

```js
var str = 'rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3)';
/* Goal: rgb(14,48,71) */

var rgx = /^rgba\(((,?\s*\d+){3}).+$/

console.log (str.replace(rgx, 'rgb($1)'));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier to extract the numbers and rebuild the string rather than trying to remove all the parts you don't want.

```js
var str = 'rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3)';
var [r,g,b] = str.match(/[\d\.]+/g);
var rgb = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
console.log(rgb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You had errors in your expression:

1. You weren't considerin spaces before the alpha value
2. You weren't escaping the `.` character

```js
var str = 'rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3)';
/* Goal: rgb(14,48,71) */
var regex = /^rgba\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+\.\d+)\)$/;

console.log (str.replace(regex, 'rgb($1,$2,$3)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
var answer = "rgb(" + str.split(",")[0].match(/\d+/)[0] + "," + str.split(",")[1] + "," + str.split(",")[2] + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a wider range of color and alpha values (e.g. `30%`, `.0`, `.5e10`, all of which are valid), you'll need to be a bit looser with your regular expression. Consider:

```
/\brgba\((.+?),[^,]+?\)/g
```

This will match any `rgba(R, G, B, A)` expression and capture all of the argument except the last. The JavaScript `replace` call would look like this:

```
str.replace(/\brgba\((.+?),[^,]+?\)/g, 'rgb($1)')
```

You can see it in action in the below snippet:

```js
const MATCH_CSS_RGBA = /\brgba\((.+?),[^,]+?\)/g;
const MATCH_CSS_RGBA_REPLACEMENT = 'rgb($1)';

function replaceRgbaWithRgb(input) {
  return input.replace(MATCH_CSS_RGBA, MATCH_CSS_RGBA_REPLACEMENT);
}

/*** the below is just for demonstration purposes ***/
const [input, output] = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
function testReplace() {
  output.value = replaceRgbaWithRgb(input.value);
}
input.addEventListener('input', testReplace);
testReplace(input);
```

```css
textarea{display:block;font-family:monospace;width:80%;height:80px;white-space:pre}
```

```html
In (edit me!):
<textarea>i.cat1{background:rgb(249, 115, 0);}  /* RGB with 3 params */
i.cat2{background:rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.99);}  /* RGBA with 4 params */
i.cat3{background:rgba(1e2, .5e1, .5e0, +.25e2%);} /* ~exotic numbers~ */</textarea>

Out:
<textarea disabled></textarea>
```

...or on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/6mZDuC/1